# I have been making an News API project in android studio but have volley got error in it. Error- com.android.volley.AuthFailureError. Using json

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, android-volley

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RequestQueue requestQueue;
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        List<news_Objects> newsList = new ArrayList<>();
 
        //url for News API 

        String url="https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=apple&from=2021-08-31&to=2021-08-31&sortBy=popularity&apiKey=ca3d6c89eff24db2a8ef78868f0af555";

//making json object request
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArr = response.getJSONArray("articles");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject newsDetail = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);

//class name news_Objects created 

                        news_Objects news = new news_Objects();

                        String imtUrl = newsDetail.getString("urlToImage");
                        String title = newsDetail.getString("title");
                        String detail = newsDetail.getString("description");
                        String newsUrl = newsDetail.getString("url");
                        String content = newsDetail.getString("content");

                        news.setNewsImageUrl(imtUrl);
                        news.setNewsTitle(title);
                        news.setNewsDetail(detail);
                        news.setNewsUrl(newsUrl);
                        news.setContent(content);
                        newsList.add(news);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("fine", "Something Wrong"+error);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something Wrong "+error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(request);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please format the code properly, add the stack trace of the error. It would help others understand your question better.

Comment: Can you add the error message and possibly stacktrace to your question?

Comment: The URL also seems to be returning a 401 error saying the API Key is invalid. I think that might be your issue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your API Key is Invalid please check your API key. Getting this response:
{"status":"error","code":"apiKeyInvalid","message":"Your API key is invalid or incorrect. Check your key, or go to https://newsapi.org to create a free API key."}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Your API key is not live, please check your API key status than again hit the api.